# Can not install HAXM on my computer

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, haxm, android-sdk-manager

have anyone an idea about how can I install HAXM on my computer? Cause when I tried to install it I've obtain an error and I don't know why.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEGrX.png

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

- Go to *Control Panel* → *Programs and Features*.
- Click on *Turn Windows features on and off*.
- Uncheck *Hyper-V* option and restart your computer.

Now you should be able to install HAXM

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable your Intel Virtualisation in your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

HAXM virtualization works only for Intel CPUs that have hardware-virtualization support. If you are running on an Intel CPU that does not have this, or even an AMD CPU you cannot install HAXM.